# Telerik "radconfirm" doesn't raise href when press "OK" on Chrome

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, webforms, telerik, asp.net-ajax

From today, I had some trouble with the Telerik RadConfirm popup message on ASPX LinkButton. After the first click on the LinkButton, the message appears and if I press "OK" nothing happens, and no error messages are visibile in browser JS console. If I press the LinkButton again, the PostBack event starts as it should have had on first click.

This behaviour seems to exist only in Chrome. Firefox, Edge and Opera are not affected. This issue appeared only from today, and the behaviour is the same in every website we have online.

This is an example. Note that every piece of code that is written with same scope shows same behaviour.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="docSaveBtn" runat="server" Text="Save" 
SkinID="linkButton_blue" OnClick="docSaveBtn_Click" 
OnClientClick="return radconfirm('Are you sure?', event, null ,null, null, '');" />
```

In page, the rendered HTML is the following:

```
<a onclick="return radconfirm('Are you sure?', event, null ,null, null, '');" 
id="MC_docSaveBtn" class="linkButton_blue" aria-disabled="false" 
href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$MC$docSaveBtn&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, true))">Save</a>
```

**Update 1**

Writing `null` rather than `event` fixes the issue on other ASPX controls, like ImageButton. Just to explain it, here's an example:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgDuplica" runat="server" 
ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/AQP.v.1.0.0.1/Images/16x16/documenti.png" 
SkinID="documents_image_small" OnClick="imgDuplica_Click" ToolTip="Duplica Gara"
OnClientClick="return radconfirm('Procedere alla duplicazione della gara?', null, null, null, null, '');"  />
```

Again, the rendered HTML is the following:

```
<input type="image" name="ctl00$MC$uc_RisultatoRicercaGara$rgResults$ctl00$ctl08$imgDuplica" 
id="ctl00_MC_uc_RisultatoRicercaGara_rgResults_ctl00_ctl08_imgDuplica" title="Duplica Gara" 
src="../../App_Themes/AQP.v.1.0.0.1/Images/16x16/documenti.png" 
onclick="return radconfirm('Procedere alla duplicazione della gara?', null, null, null, null, '');WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$MC$uc_RisultatoRicercaGara$rgResults$ctl00$ctl08$imgDuplica&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))">
```

`null` or just `return radconfirm('');` doesn't work on LinkButton on Chrome 73. Other controls work, and all controls work on different browsers.

The fix to create an event and then PostBack from inside, doesn't work well. I need to pass the HREF to the event, and it is unfeasible to create an event on every radconfirm I already have on my project.

Comment: Please check my answer, I have updated it.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how this worked at the first place. The LinkButton opens the Confirm Dialog, however, the PostBack that follows will interrupt the actions. To prevent the PostBack, in the ClientClick event handler try calling the `radconfirm()` method instead of returning it, then `return false;` after the method is executed. Check out the [Calling RadConfirm via JavaScript](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/window/alert,-confirm,-prompt-dialogs/radconfirm-dialog#calling-radconfirm-via-javascript) article to see an example of using RadConfirm.

Furthermore, the callBackFunction, "**event**" which is used for the radconfirm is invalid as there is a built-in method called [Window.event()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event) and will conflict with it.

Try changing the callBackFunction to something else, like: eventFn, myEvent, basically to anything that does not conflict with existing/built-in functions.

Here is an example of the right approach that you can try:

HTML markup and Client-Side

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function eventFn(args) {
        if (args)
            __doPostBack('<%= docSaveBtn.ClientID %>', "");
    }
</script>

<asp:LinkButton ID="docSaveBtn" runat="server" Text="Save"
    SkinID="linkButton_blue" OnClick="docSaveBtn_Click"
    OnClientClick="radconfirm('Are you sure?', eventFn, null ,null, null, ''); return false;" />

<telerik:RadWindowManager ID="RadWindowManager1" runat="server"></telerik:RadWindowManager>
```

C# - Server Side

```
protected void docSaveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

**Update**

1. Once again, client-side events needs to be executed and not returned. Call the function directly instead of writing return in the front.
2. Both the LinkButton and ImageButtons will do a postback by default, and to prevent that, you will need to cancel the event. Inside the ClientClick event, right after calling the `radconfirm()` function, write `return false`. E.g. `radconfirm("Something"); return false;`
3. Now, the RadConfirm will pop-up and you have the option to click "OK" or "Cancel". By clicking on OK, the application will not know what to do next unless you use a CallBack function. You will need to add a callback function to the RadConfirm which you can use to do the postback manually. This is described in the link I have shared above.

Here is how the button should be configured:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgDuplica" runat="server"
    ImageUrl="https://via.placeholder.com/40x20" OnClick="imgDuplica_Click" ToolTip="Duplica Gara"
    OnClientClick="radconfirm('Procedere alla duplicazione della gara?', thisIsMyCallBackFunction, null, null, null, ''); return false;" />
```

The callback function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function thisIsMyCallBackFunction(confirmation) {
        if (confirmation == true) {
            __doPostBack('<%= imgDuplica.ClientID %>', "");
        }
    }
</script>
```

Also, why not use the Telerik buttons which come with built-in Confirm Dialog functionality?

- [Button - Confirm Dialog](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/controls/examples/integration/buttonconfirmdialog/defaultcs.aspx?product=button)
- [Button - Confirm Postback](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/button/examples/confirm/defaultcs.aspx)

Comment: Your solution works only with LinkButton ASPX Controls. If RadConfirm is added to any other button, that ASPX renders as <input>, the issue persists (becouse inputs doesn't have "href" tag). Thank you so much, do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Well, my answer is targeting the control you have mentioned in the question. Could you please be more specific about the other buttons? Are they ASP Buttons, Telerik Buttons, Generic HTML buttons. Do you want to target multiple buttons or specific ones? Please update your initial question, add the rest of the information and we will then suggest things accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your support so far. I updated my original question